# Label not showing up as transparent... or showing at all

Tags: node-editor, transparency

Any ideas why this label is not showing up transparent? I believe I have all my nodes correct. These nodes are so complex someone should start a online Blender NODES academy... [image]

Comment: Can you upload your file (with the texture packed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On't use a mix shader but an RBG mix to combine the color and the texture
[image]

Comment: Using the nodes as seen above I still can't get the label to display.  See here:  http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/Untitled-1.jpg
And just to understand --why do I use a RGB mixer vs. a regular mixer?

Comment: Mix shader is... well...for mixing shaders, in this case you only have one shader... What you want is the texture to be part of the color.

Comment: Okay.. so, almost there... I did not know I had to click "assign" so that  helped and made the label actually show up on the object, but with a white-ish packground. Then by taking the alpha and plugging it into the TOP color it seemed to have finally made the background transparent --however at the cost of making the orange part of the label washed out.  As seen here: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/Untitled-2.jpg  Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Use the alpha for the factor not for the color.

Comment: the unconnected socket on the mix node is the color for the background, if I understand this correctly you want that to be black, so set that value to black (or whatever color you need) http://i.stack.imgur.com/wXxjD.gif

Comment: SUCCESS! Thank you - by bringing my attention to the 'Color 1' node I tried plugging the Alpha node into that too -- and it worked.  I now have a transparent background.

Comment: I had already clicked the green arrow.